# IIS Server w3wp process high non paged pool & thread causing poor performance

Tags: multithreading, iis, w3wp

I have 6 "identical" x64 IIS6 Servers containing the same content.
Occasionally on one or more servers we observer slow running, it can take around 20 seconds to load a simple html page.

When this happens we can see an increase in threads to 300 (normally 80) and the non paged pool 1000k (normally 200k).

Can't see much else that is different, i.e. Other Processes, Disk I/O.

The network counters appear to shifting less data, but I’s say this was symptomatic.

Anyone know what would cause a high Non paged pool?  This is a x64 server, maybe I’m looking in the wrong place

Comment: I think those things are both consequences and not the issue. When you're slow, you wind up with more connections at a time (because it takes you longer to get around to finishing and closing them). This means more threads and more non-paged pool. (Think about a fast food restaurant. If it takes longer to serve customers, it will have more customers on line, more cars in the drive through, and so on.)

Comment: Sometimes I experience a similar thing on our IIS - for half a minute, maybe, it is very slow and no request is being completed in that period. I still don't know whether it's the web server or the database which is unresponsive at that moment.

Comment: Yes I understand what you're saying, can't help but think (probabaly due to my x32 day of exhausting kernal memory) that non paged pool is key.

Comment: I was going to analyse client location, I know we have multiple domains which are widespread. 
I've also just tried creating a webgarden, where 3x worker processes were spawned, which resulted in the same increase across threads and np pool for all 3 w3wps.

Comment: Solved!

The issue was with a DC, both problematic IIS servers were using the same authentication server, once we moved them to another DC normal service resumed.

This would explain the heighted non paging pool as authenication has to be done in kernel mode.

Now to look at the dodgy DC.....

Comment: I also see this DC issue which causes the worker processes to increase in NPPool size >3000K, which is seems it cannot recover from, until I swap the connected DC and/or I stop connections to it for a moment or two.  
If you check the IIS logs for the following sub code: 2148074257, it indicates a DC issue.
We have users from multiple trusted domains.

See more info on the 500 error here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/kristinw/archive/2013/06/04/server-says-no-iis-error-500-0-2148074257-across-a-forest-trust.aspx